# How to deduce array size from an enum template argument?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, enums

How should I change the code below so that `Array<Index> array;` is enough and the `SIZE` is automatically deduced from the enum?
Even if the enum changes, it is guaranteed that it contains `SIZE` referring to the correct size.

```
template <typename Enum, int N>
class Array {

public:
    int& operator[](Enum index) { return array[index]; }

private:
    int array[N];
};

enum Index { X, Y, SIZE };

int main() {

    Array<Index, SIZE> array;

    array[X] = 1;

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:** As for "Array<type> means you're creating an array of Type objects" (Jerry) and "the name of class template is a bit misleading" (Nawaz): actually **I am creating CustomSqlQueryModel<TableColumns>. The above is just a simplified code, nothing more. Jerry and Nawaz are rigth: this simplified code is unfortunate.**

Comment: You can't calculate a count of enum elements in an enum.

Comment: True but in my case it is guaranteed to have a `SIZE` referring to the number of elements.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a traits class.  This requires a bit of extra work each time you define a new enum type, but no extra work for each occurrence of Array<Index> in user code:

```
template<class Enum>
struct ArrayTraits;

template<class Enum>
struct Array {
  int& operator[](Enum index) { return array[index]; }

private:
  int array[ArrayTraits<Enum>::size];
};

enum Index { X, Y, SIZE };

template<>
struct ArrayTraits<Index> {
  enum { size = SIZE };
};


int main() {
  Array<Index> array;
  array[X] = 1;
  return 0;
}
```

One of the advantages of this is you can specialize the traits for external enums you don't control, as long as you know how to get the max size.

Comment: @Ali: Also, if you're using code generation for these enums (generated from a schema of some kind, for example), then this boilerplate traits is very easy to keep updated.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, I don't think you can. If, however, you change it to something like:

```
struct Index { 
    enum { X, Y, SIZE};
};
```

Then your template could be something like:

```
template <class Enum>
class Array { 
// ...

private:
    int array[Enum::SIZE];
};
```

...and if the type you pass as `Enum` doesn't include some positive constant named `SIZE`,the instantiation won't compile. For the purpose at hand, you'd really kind of prefer that `Index` was a namespace, but since a namespace isn't a type, I don't think you can use it as a template argument.

I should add, however, that I'm not sure I like this idea at all -- most people are going to think `Array<type>` means you're creating an array of `Type` objects, and this is clearly something entirely different from that...

Comment: Thanks. The problem with the struct approach is that you will have to write: array[Enum::X] = 1; and that is just ugly :( As for "Array<type> means you're creating an array of Type objects" you are right, actually I am creating CustomSqlQueryModel<TableColumns>. Probably I should have come up with a better simplified example code.

Comment: C++0x's new enumerations will allow you to pass the enumeration type and say `Enum::Size` then directly, without needing to wrap in a class

Comment: @Johannes Cool :) Please post it as an answer!

Comment: @Ali: you'll also have to say `Enum::X` because those are scoped enum although IMNSHO this is a **good** thing. Stating the `enum` kind before its enumerator gives context to the reader.

Comment: @Matthieu Could you please expand on this? I am afraid I do not follow :(

Comment: @Ali: I prefer to write `Enum::X` that `kEnum_X`, both precise context, but the scoped enumerator is better integrated with other scopes (namespaces, classes). Plain `X` I just find meaningless, because several enums could define a `X` and they are unlikely to interact well.

Comment: @Matthieu Yes, I agree with you in general. However in my case, writing Enum::X would be superfluous. Do I HAVE TO qualifiy in C++0X? I just looked it up and it seems to me I do not have to, it is optional.

Comment: @Ali: you have to if you use scoped enums (those declared with either `struct` or `class`) and you don't for the old ones.

Comment: @Matthieu Hmm, that is bad news. Can I bring them in scope as with namespaces like: `using Enum;`? I guess not.

Comment: @Ali, classic enums will also have scopes (it's a bit ugly in the draft, as they are not "scopes enumerations", yet you can use '::' on them). I.e `enum A { X };` will allow you to say both `X` and `A::X`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the *size* to be template argument, not the *type* , as from your example it seems that the *type* of the array would be always `int`, then why don't you implement this:

```
template <int size>
class Array {

public:
    int& operator[](int index) { return array[index]; }

    //Note this addition!
    int operator[](int index) const { return array[index]; }
private:
    int array[size];
};

int main() {

    Array<10> array;

    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 2;

    return 0;
}
```

Note this addition: it's better if you implement const version of `operator[]` too, so that `const Array<>` can use it to access the array elements, otherwise your class wouldn't work for `const Array<>`.

Comment: I need the enum template argument, it makes accessing array elements safe. There is no such safety with `int`-s. Thanks for the answer anyhow.

Comment: @Ali: What safety you're talking about? And how exactly it is achieved with enum? Please explain.

Comment: @Nawaz In my example code you can only access elements through the enum indexes. In other words you can only access elements that MUST be in the array. If you use ints (as you propose) you can happily write array[13] = 14; etc which is a bug.

Comment: @Ali: Even in case of enum, you can write array[13]=14. Have you not tried it? All you need to cast the `int` to `Index` . See this : http://www.ideone.com/o0L1M

Comment: @Nawaz Yes, it does not compile :)

Comment: @Ali: Did you see the link I've given?

Comment: @Nawaz Yes, if you cast you can but it is your responsibility then, as it always is when it comes to casts. As I have written in the update I use this array to access columns in a database table, and I do not want to use int-s and magic numbers for that, I need the column names in the enum.

Comment: @Ali: Same responsibility is with `int` also. Beside how would you iterate through your array if you don't cast? You cannot iterate, say in `for` loop, without the cast!

Comment: @Ali: The type of all the columns in your database table, is `int`? Also, if it is designed to access database table, then I would say the name is bit misleading!

Comment: @Nawaz Yes, but I do not write loops. I use it for accessing columns in a database table which have meaningful names.

Comment: @Ali: that makes sense now. But the name of class template is a bit misleading as I said.

Comment: @Nawaz Yes, that is correct, I did write that in the update ("Jerry is right...").

Comment: @Nawaz OK, I just mentioned you in the update. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @Ali: I didn't really understand it. But I would say this doesn't seem to be a good design: 1) first of all, the name is misleading, 2) the type of all the columns in the database table, should be `int`. 3) you cannot iterate through your *array*. Anyway, all the best for whatever you're doing!

Comment: @Nawaz I can just repeat myself: I am creating custom SQL queries, and it is perfectly fine to pass a template argument enum with the column NAMES (not types) to it. I am NOT iterating through any array. My code is just a simplified code.